# Difference between "using namespace name::space;" vs "namespace name::space{}"?

Tags: c++

I have a namespace defined in `A.h`

```
namespace org::lib{
   bool xyz = true;
}
```

I have `B.cpp`

```
    #include A.h

    namespace org::lib {
        void function() {
          if (lib::xyz){
             //....
          }
        }
    }
```

Why is `lib::xyz` in `void function()` able to correctly find 'xyz'? Since I'm already under `org::lib` namespace in `B.cpp`, doing an `lib::xyz` will try to find `org::lib::lib` namespace, which doesn't exist. What am I missing?

Now, if I change `B.cpp` to be:

```
#include A.h

using namespace org::lib;
namespace{
   void function() {
     if (lib::xyz){
       //....
     }
   }
}
```

Now the `lib::xyz` is unidentified, and I have to replace it with `xyz`.

I guess it boils down to, what is the difference between:

```
using namespace org::lib
```

vs

```
namespace org::lib{

}
```

Are they not both saying "the following code is now under the namespace org::lib ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name lookup proceeds from the scope the name is *used* outwards.

In the first example, the definition of `function` is nested inside `namespace lib` which is nested inside `namespace org`. When `lib` is looked up, first the function itself is searched, then `org::lib`, then `org`, and naturally `lib` is there.

In the second example, names from `org::lib` are brought into scope in the global namespace. Nothing is done with names from `org`.